Problem with Solidify Modifier
I am a Blender beginner and as my fist 3D project I wanted to create a Cookie Cat shaped cutter. It came pretty easy to create the plain shape

But now I am stuck in this situation: when I try to apply some thickness to the mesh with the Solidify modifier I get this.

I have already checked if there were any double vertices or zero-area faces and I solved a bit but the problem is still there. Could anyone advise on what might be causing this issue or suggest a solution? Thank you very much 
Edit:
Here's the file 


I would advise to share your file. Have you applied the scale in object mode?

Sharing the file would let us give more definitive answers. Short of that, try recalculating your normals. A to select everything in Edit mode, then Shift+N to recalculate normals.

Thank you for your comments! Sorry if I took a while to answer. Next time I'll upload the file (since the post has been closed) in order to be more clear, also recalculating normals it resolved my problem. Thank you very much!

I forgot to mention that editing your question queues it up for reopening, my bad @Rekov could you post your solution as an answer? That way we could upvote it and OP would have an answer to mark as a solution to his question.

Additional tip, it's good to check your normals once in a while when modeling. The Face Orientation Overlay is great at showing such issues. Some people leave it enabled all the time (though change the colors to be less eye-burning)

Faces have an orientation, a front side and a back side. You can see this very clearly if you enable Backface culling in the Viewport Shading options menu:

The Solidify modifier takes into account the orientation of a face when it creates the geometry to thicken it. All contiguous faces need to be oriented the same way for the modifier to work properly.

Often this can be achieved by automatically recalculating normals. Press A to select the whole mesh, and Shift+N to recalculate normals.
Sometimes this can result in all of the normals pointing the wrong direction. This occurs most often when you have concave geometry. You can flip all of the normals around by pressing Alt+N, then pressing F. If automatically recalculating normals fails, you can flip the normals of individual faces by selecting them and using those same keyboard inputs.
